# ngRepeat dont refresh when I change the values - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm doing a application to a calendar and I create a function that everytime change the values of my variable called "$scope.days", when I was using the version 1.0 didnt give error, but now the ngRepeat doesnt refresh, the new values go to the variable, but the ngRepeat dont show the new result...

```
$scope.loadMonth = function()
{
    $scope.titleCalendar = $scope.months[$scope.month-1].name + ' ' + $scope.year;
    getTotalFebruary($scope.year);

    var dtString = $scope.year + '/' + $scope.month + '/' + 1,
    date        = new Date(dtString),
    day         = 1,
    weekday     = date.getDay(),
    totalDays   = $scope.months[date.getMonth()].qty + date.getDay();

    $scope.days = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
    {
        if(i < weekday)
            $scope.days.push('');
        else
            $scope.days.push(day++);
    }
};
```

my html:

```
<div class="day" ng-repeat="day in days"><p>{{ day }}</p></div>
```

If I put an alert after push new values, I can see the new values, but my ngRepeat doesnt refresh the results, I already try many things but didnt work. Somebody know the solution?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving in your console window??

Comment: In HTML about the ng-repeat put `{{days|json}}` and see what is the output

Comment: I was seeing in firefox developer tools and doesn't give error, but by the firebug, was giving ngRepeat:dupes so I put what is recommended http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat:dupes and it worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve given the small sample of code you provided but if you look at this sample you'll see that it should update the display every time you click the click me text, just enter either 1,2, or 3 in the input area. you might want to check that looping logic of yours.

```
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="mainModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="monthModel" placeholder="enter 1 2 or 3"/>
        <h1 ng-click="loadMonth(monthModel)">Click Me to Repeat</h1>         
        <span class="day" ng-repeat="day in days">{{ day }} , </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("mainModule", []);

        app.controller("mainController", function ($scope) {
        //$scope.monthModel = 1; // default some date
        $scope.year = "2014";
        $scope.months = [
                        {"name":"January", "qty":10},
                        {"name":"February", "qty":5},
                        {"name":"March", "qty":10},                     
                        ];
        $scope.loadMonth = function(monthModel)
        {
            $scope.month = monthModel;
            $scope.titleCalendar = $scope.months[$scope.month-1].name + ' ' + $scope.year;
            //getTotalFebruary($scope.year);        

            var dtString = $scope.year + '/' + $scope.month + '/' + 1,
            date        = new Date(dtString),
            day         = 1,
            weekday     = date.getDay(),
            totalDays   = $scope.months[date.getMonth()].qty + date.getDay();

            $scope.days = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
            {
                //if(i < weekday)
                //  $scope.days.push('');
                //else
                    $scope.days.push(day++);

                console.log($scope.days) ;
            }
        };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```